# generating a random value with a while loop: random value repeating itself

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am making a program that semi-randomly generates a string in a part of it I randomly generate a length for the string then I use a mix of generating random characters and random words until the length is reached: the problem is when running it whenever it generates a random word or a random string it does not regenerate it again but uses the same one it previously generated.

I've tried rewriting the code in lots of different ways but I ended up with this problem each time. I could not find anything that helped me on the internet either.

```
    rand5 = random.randrange(1, 5)
    while run < rand5:

        if random.randrange(1, 3) == 1:
            search_item_part = generate_word() + " "

        else:
            print(2)
            rand7 = random.randrange(2, 9)
            while run1 <= rand7:
                search_item_part += random.choice(letters_characters)
                run1 += 1
                if run1 == rand7:
                    search_item_part += " "
        search_item += search_item_part
        run += 1
    return search_item
```

I expect the outputs to be different words and strings but they end up being things like:

"cysticercosis cysticercosis CaE6k   cysticercosis CaE6k "
"nY3J KnY3J KnY3J Kpriming "
'F  jQel iF  jQel iF  jQel i'

Comment: The shown part of the code is not printing your output. Please provide a [repro].

Comment: You need to reset `search_item_part = ""` at the start of the loop. Or at least at the start of the `else` part.

Comment: You probably also need to reset `run1`, but that is not clear from the code given.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different words and strings each time, then I suggest saving the randomly generated word to a list. Then, add a check to make sure the newly generated word is not in that list. This way you will get a new word each time.